# should play 2 xx App have both build.sbt and build.scala

Tags: java, mysql, scala, build

I am trying to go through a tutorial which was properly made using play 1xx but I am using play.2.3.5.
The old project has build.scala in the project/ folder. The new play 2.3.5 has only build.sbt in the root of the project. I do get errors when I try to create a new file build.scale in the project subdirectory.  The question is how do I had the following settings from the build.scala of the old project to my build.sbt without bothering to create to file build.scala to my project -

build.scala -

> val appDependencies = Seq( javaCore, javaJdbc, javaEbean, "mysql" %
>   "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18" )

This' the settings in my build.sbt -

build.sbt -

> name := """wefarm"""
>
> version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
>
> lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
>
> scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
>
> libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
>     javaJdbc,
>     javaEbean,
>     cache,
>     javaWs
>   )

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just move those dependencies into the `libraryDependencies` seq of `build.sbt` and you will be ready to go.

It is still possible (and sometimes nicer) to have both `.sbt` and `project/*.scala` build configuration. Read the sbt docs for details about `.sb`t vs `.scala` build definitions:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Basic-Def.html